# Squeeze in an entry to a dictionary while creating the latter with enumerate function

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, enumerate, dict-comprehension

Is there a way of writing the following on a single line?

```
x = {item: i for i, item in enumerate([letters for letters in ascii_lowercase])}
x[' '] = 27
```

I tried something like

```
x = {item: i for i, item in enumerate([letters for letters in ascii_lowercase]), ' ': 27}
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python >=3.5 solution using dict expansion

```
x = {**{item: i for i, item in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}, **{' ' : 27}}
```

With that said, your solution is very readable and I would prefer it over this. But this is the closest you can get to what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ascii_lowercase` comes from the built-in string module, you'd do this:

```
{item: i for i, item in enumerate(ascii_lowercase + ' ')}
```

But should the index sequence start at 0 or 1? You can control that via the `start` argument of `enumerate` (the default value is 0).

If the sequence must be 0-based *and* you need to skip index 26, you'll need to do something like

```
{item: i for i, item in (*enumerate(ascii_lowercase), (27, ' '))}
```